# Absolute value of a value in List in Python

Tags: python

In Python, how do convert all the values in a list to their abs values? I would like a deep copy of the original list with the absolute values. 
say

```
a=[['2.40', '1970-1990', 'Austria']]
```

I just want `a[0][0]` values to change into their abs values. Creating new list is a ok option for me.

Comment: Can you describe the absolute value concept in more detail?  It's not [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteValue.html), I gather.

Comment: What is the absolute value of `'Austria'`?

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner example I think:

```
a=[['2.40', '1970-1990', 'Austria']]

b = []

for i in a[0]:
    try:
        b.append(abs(float(i)))
    except: 
        b.append(i)


print(b)

[2.4, '1970-1990', 'Austria']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['2.40', '1970-1990', 'Austria'] #your old list (with the extra [] removed, they seem not to have a point... If you need them you can easily edit the code appropriately)
b = [] #a new list with the absolute values
for i in range(0, len(a)): #going through each of the values in a
     try:
          b += [abs(float(a[i]))] #trying to take the absolute value and put it in the new list (I have the float() because it appears that your 2.40 is a string. If you have it as an actual integer or float (such as 2.40 instead of '2.40') you can just use abs(a[i])
     except:
          b += [a[i]] #if taking the absolute value doesn't work it returns the value on its own.
print(b)
```

Comment: Thanks I got it now. a simple float function. I was using int function which didnt seem to work with my values!!

Comment: I don't see how this code snippet is correct: * you are doing for i in a and then a[i] which is wrong * b is a list and it is preferable do something like b.append(...) instead of b+=.

Comment: My apologies, I am new to programming in general, and so I appreciate your critique. I just got slightly confused. However, I try to lend a hand wherever there is something with which I can help.
b.append() may be preferable, but b += does work, doesn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Despite the 1 error and the 1 nonconformity, however, it [i]does[/i] work to the extent that the 1 error would be quickly seen and corrected for when an error is returned. Furthermore, it solved the OP's problem, which I see as sufficient success.

Comment: My down vote was for usage of of a[i] which was incorrect. If you were posting some code you should have tried running it to check if it works, which wasn't the case with your earlier version. You may say that earlier error was easy to fix, but remember you were trying to help another beginner and the error in your answer would have put him into more confusion. If you say the error was easy to see then why weren't you able to see when you posted it. The fact is we are humans and we make mistakes, check if your code runs before posting (or say it is untested and you are outlining the approach)

Comment: Thankyou, I'll remember that in the future. I'm unfortunately busy right now, but I should have pointed out that I hadn't tested it yet.

Comment: -1 `for i in range(0, len(a)-1)` hurts my eyes severily. please try `for item in a`

Comment: I'm sorry that it hurts your eyes, but is there any actual disadvantage to it in program efficiency or reliability? I haven't seen any in my work. If there is I'll change it, but from what I've seen this seems to work just as well. Thanks

Comment: I could not see more problems in so little space. Your affirmation that the loop is `going through each of the values in a` is not True. And this falls into programming basics. Please, take 15 seconds and run your code. You already got this advice from others. It gives a **wrong answer**. If after fixing the result you want to test your way of looping through a list for efficiency, do it yourself using `timeit` trying both options (look at it first with `dis`). And in terms of readability/maintenance the difference is obvious. It is plain bad coding that produces a wrong answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry it had errors. I believe I have fixed them. I refuse to fix the
    for i in range(0, len(a))
because, honestly, you have given me no concrete reason to. Furthermore, your comment "I could not see more problems in so little space" was, frankly, rude and untrue. If you want me to post a code that's as horrible as I can, I guarantee I will make you weep for the pain in your eyes. Furthermore, I got advice to run it or state that I hadn't run it. I went with option 2 because I didn't have time to run it.

Comment: And hey, at least I'm trying to solve the OP's problem instead of just getting mad at people who are.